# razor code in external javascript treated as string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I want to add a table element after a specific element after an element run at the server but when I tried to access the id of the element it was treated as a string

I have tried showing the id or an element in an alert but it is string
I have tried to check for other posts on stack overflow but they all say the way to access is the same way that for me produces strings
I have tried putting the same code as in the string in the aspx file and it works so I know there isn't a problem with the <%=message.ClientID%>

in aspx file

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="Manager">
        <p id="message" runat="server" class="caption">
            There aren't any users in the database
        </p>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:HiddenField id="hfData" runat="server"/>
        </form>
        <script src="js/Manager.js" ></script>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

in Manager.js

```
var message = document.getElementById('<%=message.ClientID %>');
message.parentNode.insertBefore(tbl, message.nextSibling);
```

message equals to undefined when i watch it's value
and the following code doesn't execute

I have tried the following to try access the id

```
var str = '<%=message.ClientID%>';
alert(str);
```

but it alerts <%=message.ClientID%> as a string
It should produce the output of ContentPlaceHolder1_message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, try to add the Manager.js script directly to the aspx page, which worked for me. I am afraid when the .aspx page is executed on the server at that moment, Manager.js is not included as the page is rendered.

```
<p id="message" runat="server" class="caption">
     There aren't any users in the database
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var str = '<%=message.ClientID%>';
     alert(str);
</script>
```

Comment: I now got what you meant thanks, is there any way to make the script rendered for the first time at the server side and save the Id in a variable?

Comment: I am glad i was on any help

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by creating a javascript variable on the server side with razor code and then using it in the external javascript file

in aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var messageId = '<%=message.ClientID%>';
</script>
```

in Manager.js

```
var message = document.getElementById(messageId);
message.parentNode.insertBefore(tbl, message.nextSibling);
```